# Button Download in WebView Won't Work

Tags: android, android-webview

I was wondering one of website I used iframe under `WebView`, everything is working smoothly only the Button Download in the `WebView` doesn't work, and when I start the app.. It's go to open Browser to load, Have i miss something in the code below:

**Layout:**

```
<WebView 
    android:id="@+id/ringtones"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="0.55"
    android:scrollbars="none" />
```

**Activity:**

```
mWebView = new WebView(this);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.ringtones);
        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        });
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.free-ringtones.cc/android/");
```

The code above is working fine but only I can't download the ringtones file if `URL` is under `WebView`, and if open in Browser it's working as usual.

Did I make something wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: your coding is wrong ,if you are getting your webview by id ,then no need to create it by new object.

Answer (score 0):

A webview can't download files directly, you need to implement it using something similar:

```
mWebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
    public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
            String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
            long contentLength) {

      // open in external browser (for download)
      Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
      i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
      startActivity(i);

      // OR you call a method to download url to file directly
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a DownloadListener but it goes open an AppChooser to select the browser to download. I think we can't download inside the app.

```
webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength) {
            Intent appChooser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(appChooser);
        }
    });
```